# Minimum Spanning Tree that minimizes a function

Tags: graph-theory

While studying discrete mathematics I came across this problem in my math book this week:

Now, I know that in an MST the sum of weights is minimal and that all MST's are included in the set of spanning trees and I tried proving this with Kruskal's algorithm but this would only work for one minimal spanning tree, not all. Any ideas how I can approach this?

Comment: What function do you have in mind? The minimal spanning tree algorithms work because you minimize a well-behaved function (sum of weights). The same strategy will work for e.g. product of weights (take logarithms), if you think sum of squares of weights, no problem (take the squares as the weights) , for something else, it would need a *careful* look.

Answer (score 1):

Let $T$ be a minimum spanning tree of $G$. Suppose there exists a spanning tree $T'$ such that $f(T')<f(T)$. Let $e, e'$ be the corresponding edges of maximum weight in $T, T'$, respectively. If we remove $e$ from $T$, then $T$ is broken into two connected components. There must exist an edge $e''$ in $T'$ which connects these components. Clearly $w_{e''}\leqslant w_{e'}< w_e$. Thus the tree $T''$ obtained from $T$ by replacing the edge $e$ with $e''$ has weight $w(T'') = w(T) + w_{e''} - w_e < w(T)$, a contradiction.